# Cannot make outbound & inbound calls using asterisk 13 (FreePBX) and Twilio

Tags: twilio, asterisk, freepbx

I have had trouble configuring inbound and outbound calls using FreePBX with SIP provider TWilio.

As it stands I cannot make external calls or receive calls from Twilio.

I have monitored TCP port 5060 and can see traffic routed to my address when I engage a call using my number provided through Twilio but from the FreePBX cli I observe the following when I see incoming traffic.

[#DATE] NOTICE[18449]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:368 
log_unidentified_request: Request from '' failed for '54.252.254.64:5060' (callid: 41822dbe439f067b0ef90f596b3998d2@0.0.0.0) - No matching endpoint found

I have searched the web already for similar issues but have yet to come across anything of use. As this is early testing I have put the system on a DMZ to avoid the NAT firewall.

Note: This is my first post to stack overflow so I may not be correctly following the layout for posting, I apologize in advance. Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a configuration error.

Check the [setup guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/sample-configuration#asterisk). But also, I found from another user with the same error that they changed the following:

> pj_sip was set to port 5060 instead of chan_sip

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thank you for that. Adjusting chan_sip to 5060 done the trick. This corrects incoming, outgoing is not perfect but it maybe my settings I will have to look over them. If you have any information as to why I am somtimes able to send out calls and other times not that would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this case, it would probably help to send the CallSids of those problematic calls to support: https://twilio.com/help/contact and we can look into it from there.